# How to redirect https://www to non-www https version in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, https, nginx-config

I need some help with my nginx config so all my http traffic goes to https and also www changes to non-www. My server is running ubuntu 18.04 and nginx.

here is my sites-available .conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name cdn.example.com;
    return 301 https://cdn.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 http2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdn.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdn.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/html/storage;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name cdn.example.com;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css|json)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location / {
    aio threads;
    limit_rate_after 1m;
    limit_rate 3m;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    rewrite ^/index.php/(.*) /$1  permanent;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css|json)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location / {
    aio threads;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I tried so many different configuration but none of them worked for me.

Comment: The problem is your last `server` block which needs to be split into two.

Comment: @RichardSmith but mate another domain with the same configuration is working fine for me. That one is redirecting well.

Comment: You last `server` block with `listen 443 ssl;` and `server_name example.com www.example.com;` processes requests for both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` and does not attempt to redirect from one to the other.